# In Jest is there a way to deep compare objects where array order is ignored?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Consider this Jest test which I would like to pass

```
it('should be equal', function () {
    const data1 = {
        name: "Bob",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Anne",
                children: [
                    "Oliver",
                    "John"
                ]
            },
            {
                name:"Katy"
            }
        ]
    }
    const data2 = {
        name: "Bob",
        children: [
            {
                name:"Katy"
            },
            {
                name: "Anne",
                children: [
                    "John",
                    "Oliver",
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    expect(data1).toEqual(data2)
});
```

The only differences between `data1` and `data2` is the order of the `children` arrays. Is there a simple solution to allow the deep object comparison but ignore array order? (This is a simplified case my objects are much larger/deeper)

Comment: Jest extended, mentioned on https://jestjs.io/docs/expect, has a matcher for arrays in any order: https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludeallmembersmembers

Comment: That would be ok for directly checking the array, the issue is the arrays are inside objects.

Comment: All of those matchers can be use asymmetrically, too - https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#asymmetric-matchers. So you can do e.g. `expect(data1).toMatchObject({ name: data2.name, children: expect.toIncludeAllMembers(data2.children) })`. The depth might be an issue, though.